# Consolidar informacion de duplicados en excel

Tags: excel, formulas, microsoft-office, office365, calculo

Alguien tiene la solucion, o formula o estratregia para el resultado que quiero segun la imagen? Nota: ya tengo los duplicados pero no se como consolidar la informacion y eliminar el duplicado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

1. Seleccionás el rango completo

   [image: Datos origen]
2. Insertar > Tabla dinámica
3. `Cedula` como Filas, `Campo 1` y `Campo 2` como Valores (Cuenta de esos valores)
   [image: Campos de tabla dinámica]
4. Listo. Te muestra la cantidad de `X` que tiene cada cédula en cada campo.

   [image: Tabla dinámica]
5. Para que aparezca en el mismo formato que estaba originalmente, con una `X`, podés cambiar el formato de número para que muestre así. Usando como formato de número:

   ```
   "X";"";"";@
   ```

   Te queda:

   [image: Misma tabla que el resultado esperado, con "X" en vez de 1s]

Comment: No hay de qué. Buena respuesta!

Comment: Creo que los duplicados no son X como tales, sino que puso eso a modo de ejemplo, no que sean X literales como tal.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Los duplicados son en la columna `Cedula`. Las `X` son los valores que quiere combinar. Yo creo que sí, son `X` literales, ya que mucha gente usa eso como forma de marcar una especie de verdadero/falso (horrible, pero habitual) -En todo caso el autor debería aclarar y, si llegara a ser así, debería epxlicar la forma de combinar cuando un valor duplicado tiene más de un texto para un mismo ítem... Si es verdadero/falso tiene sentido, si fuese un texto libre, imposible saber lo que quiere